# NSFetchController and many-to-many in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

For better understanding my problem imagine your facebook friends; I have one entity "user" and I use that for displaying relationship between friends;

[image]

I don't know how to get friends of concrete user using `NSFetchRequest`

I have two "to many" relationship(see above) and I try to get friends using NSPredicate, but in the end array is empty.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = (NSEntityDescription *)[_dbManager userEntity];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

User *userByUid = [_dbManager userByUid:_currentUid];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"sortId" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(friends IN %@)", userByUid];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

NSArray *array = [_fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: Can't you simply call `userByUis.friends`? If you want them sorted you can use `NSSet` `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method on `friends` property.

Comment: thanks for the answer) I can't because I want to use NSFetchController that will be control all my entities;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the inverse relationship and "ANY":

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY beFriendsWith == %@", userByUid]
```